# Output is not correct

Tags: java, arrays

So, we have been tasked with the following:

You will model a particular type of solitaire. The game starts with 45 cards. (They need
not be playing cards. Unmarked index cards work just as well.) Randomly divide them
into some number of piles of random size. For example, you might start with piles of
size 20, 5, 1, 9 and 10. In each round, you take one card from each pile, forming a new
pile with these cards. For example, the sample starting configuration would be
transformed into piles of size 19, 4, 8, 9 and 5. The solitaire is over when the piles have
size 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, in some order. (It can be shown that you always end up
with such a configuration.)

We are given the SolitaireTester class, which I am providing below:

```
public class SolitaireTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Solitaire s = new Solitaire();

    System.out.println("Start: " + s.toString());

    int rounds = 0;
    while (!s.over()) {
        s.round();
        ++rounds;
        System.out.println(rounds + ": " + s.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Rounds: " + rounds);
}
}
```

We have to write the Solitaire class.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Solitaire
{
int size = 45;

private ArrayList piles;

//Constructor for the initialization of random values
public Solitaire()
{
    piles = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int temp = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        piles.add(temp);
    }
}

//toString() will return a string representation of a Solitaire object
public String toString()
{
    return piles.toString();
}

/*
 * over() will return true if the solitaire is over, false otherwise.  The solitaire is over when 
 * the piles have size 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, in some order
 */
public boolean over()
{
    int sum = 0;

    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    Iterator itr = piles.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        int check = (int) itr.next();

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == check)
            {
                a[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if(sum == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//round() takes one card from each pile, forming a new pile with these cards
public boolean round()
{
    Iterator itr = piles.iterator();

    int count = 0;

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        int check = (int) itr.next();
        count += 1;
    }

    if(count == 9)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong.  The output I get is:

```
Start: [5, 1, 2, 1, 7, 10, 5, 8, 6, 3, 8, 6, 6, 6, 10, 4, 4, 9, 7, 4, 10, 2, 8, 4, 8, 9, 10, 3, 3, 5, 9, 2, 5, 5, 3, 6, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 9, 6]
Rounds: 0
```

The actual output should have many more rounds and actually give the correct output.

If someone could point me in the right direction as to where I'm making my mistake(s).  Also, if there is anything extraneous that I'm including and shouldn't, then that would also be helpful.  Please, I am not looking for the answer, just a nudge in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: If you know what your code *should* produce, and you can see that the actual output is different, then you should be able to work your way backward to see why your expectations diverge from reality.

Comment: Can you please be a little more helpful than that?  Thank you!

Comment: You need to learn how to troubleshoot your own problem and at least identify where the code is going wrong before you can ask for help. Right now, you're asking people to spend time learning all of your code and then re-writing it correctly for you -- we don't do that here.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, or lack thereof.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Solitaire
{

int maxSize = 45;
int newPile;

private ArrayList<Integer> piles;

/*
 * Constructor for the initialization of random values.
 * Initialize piles to a random number of piles of random size, but exactly 45 cards total.
 */
public Solitaire()
{

    int totalNumberOfStartingPiles = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    boolean continueLoop = true;
    int total = 0;
    int size = 45;

    while (continueLoop)
    {
        piles = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfStartingPiles; i++)
        {
            int temp = getRandomPile(size - totalNumberOfStartingPiles + i);

            if (i == totalNumberOfStartingPiles - 1)
            {
                piles.add(size);
            } else {
                piles.add(temp);
                size = size - temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++)
        {
            total += piles.get(i);
        }

        if (total == maxSize)
        {
            continueLoop = false;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Randomizes and returns the total number of starting piles.
 * 
 * @return Integer that is the total number of starting piles.
 */
public int getRandomPile(int size)
{
    int totalNumberOfStartingPiles = (int) (Math.random() * size) + 1;
    return totalNumberOfStartingPiles;
}

/* 
 * toString() will return a string representation of a Solitaire object.
 * 
 * @return String representation of a Solitaire object.
 */
public String toString()
{
    return piles.toString();
}

/*
 * over() will return true if the solitaire is over, false otherwise. The
 * solitaire is over when the piles have size 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 
 * 9, in some order.
 * 
 * @return true if the solitaire is over, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean over()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    boolean flag = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != piles.get(i))
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}

/*
 * In each round, you take one card from each pile, forming a new pile with these cards.
 * Removes a pile that reaches a size of 0 cards.
 */
public void round()
{
    newPile = piles.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++)
    {
        piles.set(i, (piles.get(i)) - 1);

        if(piles.get(i)==0)
        {
            piles.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }

    piles.add(newPile);
    Collections.sort(piles); //sorts the pile into ascending numerical order
}
```

}

Comment: Please only put in the changed bits, rather than the full, corrected program. Give a description of how it was fixed and a sample output, as well.

Comment: The issue with that is that I had to rewrite the code from scratch as my original attempt was, effectively, garbage.  The corrected code is so much different from the original code that there really isn't a way to go through and notate all the differences.  The original code did not produce any semblance of output.  The output of the corrected code looks something like:

Comment: Start: [11, 12, 22]
1: [10, 11, 21, 3]
2: [9, 10, 20, 2, 4]
3: [8, 9, 19, 1, 3, 5]
4: [7, 8, 18, 2, 4, 6]
5: [6, 7, 17, 1, 3, 5, 6]
6: [5, 6, 16, 2, 4, 5, 7]
7: [4, 5, 15, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
8: [3, 4, 14, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
9: [2, 3, 13, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
10: [1, 2, 12, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
. . .
55: [1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
56: [1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
57: [2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
58: [1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
59: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
60: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]
Rounds: 60

Comment: However, the program I wrote will sort each pile into ascending order before it gets checked by the over() method.

Comment: Then please put that in the answer. Also, with that in mind: we tend to discourage people from thinking that SO will write their code for them, so this likely isn't a good answer for SO.

Comment: Please provide some commentary with your answers